# How to use nameof to get the fully qualified name of a property in a class in C# Attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, attributes

I am using Foolproof library in ASP.Net MVC project and in some cases I need to check a property within a member class of my model using attribues .

For example I have a user class which has a property of type Address and I need to check for the City in the Address.

The attributes need to have the name of the property in a dot notation for my example you could say "Address.City".

Of course this suffers from refactoring issues if I need to change either names later on (Address or City)

I need to use nameof for that purpose and of course if I use it like this :

```
nameof(Address.City)
```

it will produce City Only.

I need nameof because it produces constant values that are allowed in attributes.

I found that the reference tells it is possible but not how.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx
in remarks section it says:

> If you need to get the fully-qualified name, you can use the typeof expression along with nameof.

but I couldn't find any place to tell how to do this.

Can anyone help, please?
Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

**Update :** October-2019

As I looked up the documentation again they removed the above statement and replaced it with.

> As the preceding example shows, in the case of a type and a namespace, the produced name is usually not fully qualified.

Comment: Have a look at the approach the author took here, using path expressions: https://josefottosson.se/get-dot-notation-of-c-sharp-property-member/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After a bit of digging I found that this issue has been discussed already upon developing this feature in here
https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/552376
and specially in here
https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/552377
for the comment by MgSam

> As it is proposed, I can imagine something like this happening to get a fully qualified name: BindToFullyQualifiedName(nameof(Microsoft) + "." + nameof(Microsoft.Data) + "." + nameof(Microsoft.Data.Entities) + "." + nameof(Microsoft.Data.Entities.EntityObject));

The answer was

> I think typeof(EntityObject).FullName is fully sufficient in your
>   case.

Which concluded the discussion with no further comments on another way to do this.

Unfortunately this means there is no way to user nameof and get the fully qualified name directly for usage in Attributes.

Probably this is the end of it and I suppose Microsoft should change their documentation to make it more clear and precise.

Comment: "Unfortunately this means there is no way to user nameof and get the fully qualified name directly for usage in Attributes." - That's not entirely true - your first example with the chaining of + "." + will work fine (just verbose), as the expression is converted into a constant string.

Comment: Yes it would but what I mean here is that I cannot use nameof directly combined with type of (as stated in documentation) to get the result directly with no need to repeat. I think my full statement here is precise.

Comment: @Rob The problem with that is that `nameof` is designed to survive code refactors, including hierarchy changes. If you use that method, you break that functionality. What would be best is a `bool` (et. al.) parameter which indicates whether it should use the fully qualified name, or least.

Comment: I think the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn986596.aspx) are fairly clear - _Used to obtain the simple **(unqualified)** string name of a variable, type, or member_

Comment: @EBrown Sure, I agree it's not ideal, however this will still produce a compile error if the hierarchy changes (which is preferable to the existing method of just using strings)

Comment: @Stephne They were not clear on how to use nameof and typeof combined to get the fully qualified name as mentioned in my question. Not even one example for it. This is really not acceptable to leave developers with such documentation line and don't show how exactly. Shame on you Microsoft.

Comment: @AhmedSamyMoursiHashwa, There is no reason to use `nameof()` (not with foolproof data annotations at least). What is it that your trying to do?

Comment: I am now developing an MVC web application that is subject to many refactors in names so I am using nameof almost everywhere to make sure refactoring doesn't break my code (my validations in this case).

Comment: @AhmedSamyMoursiHashwa, You have an X-Y problem. There is no need for the fully qualified name when working with conditional validations (conditional validation attributes been developed long before that method even existed)

Comment: I get it but Foolproof does check for the "." in the name in case you need to check if a member of a type in a class needs to be checked. For my example it would be to check if the city is not empty then another field is required and so on.

Comment: @AhmedSamyMoursiHashwa, You not understanding how it works - If your generating a control for say `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Address.City)` it will generate `id="Address_City" name="Address.City". If you then need a comparison with another property (say) `State` , the client side script uses `lastIndexOf(".") + 1` to obtain the `Address.` part are perpends it to generate `Address.State` which is then used to find the corresponding view.

Comment: OK maybe the client side does although I had to modify it in my version of Foolproof (maybe it is a bit old or something)  but as I looked up in server side I found that it does need the full qualified name to check for the value of the property inside. To be specific please check that URL [link] (http://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Foolproof/Base%20Classes/ContingentValidationAttribute.cs) specially that method GetDependentPropertyValue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129307/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ahmed-samy-moursi-hashwa).

Answer (score 7):

So I ran into a similar issue and found two workable solutions:
If you want to have the namespaces as well just include them in the expression sent to either full name implementation

First:

```
public ref struct FullNameOf<T> 
{
    string _fullName;
    public FullNameOf(T _, [CallerArgumentExpression("_")] string fullName = "" ) 
    {
        _fullName = fullName;   
    }

    public static implicit operator string(FullNameOf<T> obj)
         => obj._fullName;
}
```

Second:

```
public static class FullName
{
    public static string Of<T>( T _, [CallerArgumentExpression( "_" )] string fullName = "" )
     => fullName; 
}
```

The usage would look something like this:

```
public class This 
{
    public class Is
    {
        public class A
        {
            public class Very
            {
                public class Nested
                {
                    public class Property
                    {
                        public static string Here = string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine( $"nameof: {nameof(This.Is.A.Very.Nested.Property.Here) }" );
Console.WriteLine( $"fullnameof: { new FullNameOf<string>(This.Is.A.Very.Nested.Property.Here) }" );
Console.WriteLine( $"fullnameof func: {FullName.Of( This.Is.A.Very.Nested.Property.Here )}" );
```

The output is:

> nameof: Here 
> fullnameof: This.Is.A.Very.Nested.Property.Here 
> fullnameof func: This.Is.A.Very.Nested.Property.Here

Comment: Nice work, it's workable and elegant, should be marked as answer.

Comment: A pity that it doens't work exactly as the standard operator "nameof" which can be put on any member either static or instance, more work is needed to find out how it was implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @Ignaz503's answer I came up with an extension method that works in C# 10 or later, and which will give the full name of a type whose name is passed in using the `nameof()` operator with a fully-qualified name:

```
public static class FullName {
    public static string Of(string _, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerArgumentExpression("_")] string fullTypeName = "") {
        if (fullTypeName.StartsWith("nameof(") && fullTypeName.EndsWith(")")) {
            return fullTypeName[7..^1];
        }
        return fullTypeName;
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
Console.WriteLine("Full name: " + FullName.Of(nameof(MyApp.Web.Extensions.MyExtensionClass)));
```

Comment: A very nice solution to lean on the nameof() operator and thus not be constrained by needing to pass an instance, have static properties, etc.  The is the type of solution that would ideally be handled internally in a future version of c#.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to specify a "reference" type (not 'reference type' in the C# sense) to get your target namespace (why should you?), and to save putting a string of `nameof` operators separated by `.`, then you can include the "base" namespace by getting the assembly name if it follows the default convention and is named the same as your default namespace, as thus:

```
$"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.{nameof(Level1Namespace)}.{nameof(Level2Namespace)}"
```

This will at least save you some code, and protect you against refactors where you change the assembly name or even move an entire hierarchy of classes to another assembly, but it of course won't protect against changes within the namespace hierarchy itself. To protect against that, then I think you will indeed need a "reference" type such as perhaps an abstract class or interface that all other classes in the desired namespace inherit, and then apply the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40856014/197591) solution to it.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but the question here is not about finding a way to extract the fully qualified name but how to use it in Attributes of properties in which case your answer is not going to work.

Comment: @AhmedSamyMoursiHashwa Ah, yes, I see. Well, I found this question searching for trying to get a fully qualified namespace for a class, so I'll leave it here for now in case it may help anyone searching for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach to getting the full name of the method including the namespace.

```
public static class FullName
    {
        public static string Of(Delegate method)
        {
            var ns = method.Method.DeclaringType?.FullName;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ns))
                return method.Method.Name;

            return (ns + "." + method.Method.Name);
        }
    }
```

Example usage:

```
// Namespace1.Class1+Class2.Method1
FullName.Of(class1.Method1)


namespace Namespace1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public class Class2
        {
            public int Method1(int int1, string str1)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```