# c# Full Name of Property in Class

Tags: c#

I have a class

```
public class MyCoolProp
{
    public string FullName {get;set;}
}
```

and in another Class i have this as Property:

```
public class MyMainClass
{
    public MyCoolProp coolprop {get;set;}

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(nameof(coolprop.FullName));
    }
}
```

The Actual Result is: "Fullname"

But i want a combination like this: "coolprop.FullName"

i dont want to do something like this:

```
nameof(coolprop) + "." + nameof(coolprop.FullName);
```

Maybe its possible in an extension?

If i rename the Property "coolprop" the output should also have the new name

Comment: I believe this might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855818/how-to-use-nameof-to-get-the-fully-qualified-name-of-a-property-in-a-class-in-c) which basically says you cannot.

Comment: @PhilMasteG: That was back in 2016 - for *some* cases, the C# 10 feature of `CallerArgumentExpression` may be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source:
[get name of a variable or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9801624/get-name-of-a-variable-or-parameter) (modified a bit adjusted with your case)

You can use what System.Linq.Expression provides
code example:

```cs
using System.Linq.Expression
class Program
{
    public static MyCoolProp coolProp { get; set; }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        coolProp = new MyCoolProp() { FullName = "John" };
        DoSomething();
    }

    public static string GetMemberName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> memberExpression)
    {
        MemberExpression expressionBody = (MemberExpression)memberExpression.Body;
        return expressionBody.ToString();
    }

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        string prop = GetMemberName(() => coolProp.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(prop);
    }

}

public class MyCoolProp
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

the `GetMemberName` method will return the namespace, class name, object name, and variable name (depends where the method is being called)

Output: `Program.coolProp.FullName`

Answer (score 8):

Depending on *exactly* what you want to do, you *might* be able to use [`CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerargumentexpressionattribute?view=net-6.0). That does mean you need to be willing to actually evaluate the property as well, even if you don't use it.

Note that this requires a C# 10 compiler.

Here's a complete example:

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class MyCoolProp
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static MyCoolProp CoolProp { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        CoolProp = new MyCoolProp { FullName = "Test" };
        WriteTextAndExpression(CoolProp.FullName);
    }

    static void WriteTextAndExpression(string text,
        [CallerArgumentExpression("text")] string expression = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{expression} = {text}");
    }
}
```

Output: `CoolProp.FullName = Test`

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @kim's linq expression solution, here's an implementation that is hopefully a closer match to the nameof(XXX.YYY) that the OP was wanting.  In particular..

- Doesn't require an object instance, i.e. works directly against the types similar to nameof()
- Also, it doesn't rely on ToString() to generate the full name, i.e. hopefully less brittle

```
public static string Of<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    static MemberExpression GetMemberExpression(Expression expression) =>
        expression as MemberExpression ?? (expression as UnaryExpression)?.Operand as MemberExpression;

    var names = new Stack<string>();
    var memberExpression = GetMemberExpression(expression.Body);

    while (memberExpression != null)
    {
        names.Push(memberExpression.Member.Name);
        memberExpression = GetMemberExpression(memberExpression.Expression);
    }

    names.Push(expression.Parameters.First().Type.Name);

    return string.Join(".", names);
}
```

Usage..

```
public class MyCoolProp
{
    public string FullName {get;set;}
    public CoolerProp AnotherProp { get; set; }
}

public class CoolerProp
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    Assert.That(Name.Of<MyCoolProp>(x => x.FullName), Is.EqualTo("MyCoolProp.FullName"));
    Assert.That(Name.Of<MyCoolProp>(x => x.AnotherProp.Name), Is.EqualTo("MyCoolProp.AnotherProp.Name"));
}
```