# StackOverflowException during serialization using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, polymorphism, system.text.json

I can't figure out why the following code is throwing a `StackOverflowException` during `Write`. I want to be able to use a type discriminator to help me serialize / deserialize objects while not losing concrete implementation details. How can I fix this issue?

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

public abstract class ClassC
{
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
    public string TypeDiscriminator => this.GetType().FullName;
}

public class ClassB : ClassC
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA : ClassB
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class PolymorphicJsonConverter<TBase> : JsonConverter<TBase> where TBase : ClassC
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeof(TBase).IsAssignableFrom(typeToConvert);

    public override TBase Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        using (var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
        {
            var root = jsonDoc.RootElement;
            var typeDiscriminator = root.GetProperty("TypeDiscriminator").GetString();

            var type = Type.GetType(typeDiscriminator);
            if (type == null)
            {
                throw new JsonException($"Type {typeDiscriminator} could not be found.");
            }

            return (TBase)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(root.GetRawText(), type, options);
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TBase value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType(), options);
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            Converters = { new PolymorphicJsonConverter<ClassC>() },
            WriteIndented = true
        };

        ClassA classA = new ClassA { PropertyA = "ValueA", PropertyB = "ValueB", PropertyC = "ValueC" };

        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<ClassC>(classA, options);
        ClassC deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ClassC>(json, options);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.WriteLine(deserialized is ClassA); // Should output 'True'
    }
}
```

Comment: I think something's fishy about the `typeToConvert` parameter in the `read` method. It is not used at all, but the `return` instruction seems to re-invoke recursively the same method, and probably it passes the same parameters - it even does not pass in the `reader` parameter. So, what is the logic behind this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your converter is calling itself recursively here:

```
return (TBase)JsonSerializer.Deserialize(root.GetRawText(), type, options);
```

The recursion occurs because your `CanConvert(Type typeToConvert)` method returns `true` for the concrete derived types of `ClassC` even though no conversion is required for them.

Since your base type is abstract, your converter can be modified as follows, adding a check inside `CanConvert` that the incoming type is abstract:

```
public class ClassCJsonConverter : JsonConverter<ClassC>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => typeToConvert.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(ClassC)) && typeToConvert.IsAbstract;

    public override ClassC? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        using (var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader))
        {
            var root = jsonDoc.RootElement;
            var typeDiscriminator = root.GetProperty("TypeDiscriminator").GetString();

            var type = typeDiscriminator == null ? null : Type.GetType(typeDiscriminator);
            if (type == null || CanConvert(type)) // Here we guarantee there is no infinite recursion.
                throw new JsonException($"Type {typeDiscriminator} could not be found or is invalid.");

            return (ClassC?)root.Deserialize(type, options);
        }
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, ClassC value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, value.GetType(), options);
}
```

The assumption made by this version is that any type assignable to `ClassC` is either abstract (and so requires type resolution) or is concrete (and does not require type resolution).  If you had non-abstract base types then this strategy would not work, and you would need to adopt a more complex strategy of disabling the converter during the recursive call such as the one shown in *[How to use default serialization in a custom System.Text.Json JsonConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65430420/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nKbAFY).

**As an alternative**, as of **.NET 7**, support for polymorphic type discriminators is built into System.Text.Json and no converter is required.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74352597/3744182) to *[Is polymorphic deserialization possible in System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58074304/3744182)*.  Using this approach your types can be round-tripped with the following attributes applied:

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ClassB), nameof(ClassB))]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ClassA), nameof(ClassA))]
[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "TypeDiscriminator")]
public abstract class ClassC
{
    public string PropertyC { get; set; }
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ClassB), nameof(ClassB))]
[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "TypeDiscriminator")]
public class ClassB : ClassC
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

[JsonDerivedType(typeof(ClassA), nameof(ClassA))]
[JsonPolymorphic(TypeDiscriminatorPropertyName = "TypeDiscriminator")]
public class ClassA : ClassB
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}
```

You may need to modify the type discriminator values passed to the [`[JsonDerivedType(Type derivedType, string typeDiscriminator)]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonderivedtypeattribute.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-serialization-jsonderivedtypeattribute-ctor(system-type-system-string)) attribute constructors to include the C# namespaces, as [`nameof(type)` does not include the C# namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40855818).

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Vsk1mX).

Answer (score 0):

In your `Write` method, you are invoking your `Write` method again - you have a loop - after some time, your app is out of memory. Put a breakpoint in the `Write` method and see.

You should use a `writer` in the `Write` method. This is [the sample basic converter example from the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#sample-basic-converter):

```
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace SystemTextJsonSamples
{
    public class DateTimeOffsetJsonConverter : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset>
    {
        public override DateTimeOffset Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
                DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(reader.GetString()!,
                    "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            DateTimeOffset dateTimeValue,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
                writer.WriteStringValue(dateTimeValue.ToString(
                    "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}
```